# Sensible debugging in Eclipse of STL containers

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb

I am confused as to how is one supposed to debug STL containers in eclipse. The `Variables` window just shows the container internal variables, not the collection of objects, that I am storing in it. From there, I can only expand `m_start` pointer to see the first element. And that's it.

Currently, I am solving this problem by accessing gdb directly from the console: `p myvect[0]@10` will print the first 10 elements of a vector.

There is [this](https://blogs.williamhuang.org/?p=44) article, urging students in some university to download some python script. My issues with the article are 1) My Eclipse Luna lacks the exact menus they explain about 2) this sentence: "According to its official documentations, there exists a unresolved bug and you should revise it by yourself in the source file."

I heard Visul Studio presents something called "Raw view".

To me, it sounds quite simple and very important to have built-in STL container debugging capabilities for Eclipse CDT. Do they exist? If no, why were they not implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention your platform.

On "recent" (at least the last couple of years, probably longer) Linux distros, everything is set up to "just work".  Of course there's a lot of machinery backing this, and all the bits must be in place:

- Your gdb must be Python-enabled
- The pretty-printers for libstdc++ must be installed in a way that causes them to automatically activate when debugging
- Your Eclipse must tell gdb that it understands pretty-printing

As I said, in a recent environment all of this works.  You can try it out by hand using gdb in the terminal and printing some STL data structure; even just a string will do.  If you get incomprehensible goo, then something isn't set up properly.

If you aren't on a Linux distro you can try to set this stuff up by hand.  It's a bit more involved to do so, but there are some instructions on the gdb wiki that are reasonable enough.